# nginx two different error_pages for same error code

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want to configure a maintenance page for Nginx.

I wanted to differentiate the 503 maintenance page with other 503 pages.

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if (-f /www/maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        }
        ...
    }


    # Error pages.
    error_page 503 /maintenance_on.html;
    location = /maintenance_on.html {
        root /www/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to serve maintenance_on.html only when it is present. For all the 503s where maintenance_on.html is not there, I want to serve 50x.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate [`error_page` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for handling 503. You can point it at a [named `location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) with a [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

For example:

```
error_page 503 @error503;
error_page 500 502 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
}
location @error503 {
    root   html;
    try_files /maintenance_on.html /50x.html =404;
}
```

The `@error503` block will first check for the existence of the file `maintenance_on.html` and if it does not exist, the file `50x.html` instead. The `=404` term is not reached.

Comment: Could you please explain the @error503 block?